# Hyperledger Fabric Chaincode - Failed to read data from another chaincode using InvokeChaincode. Status 200 but Payload is Empty

Tags: go, hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am working on a chaincode where I need to read data previously stored from another one.

They are instantiated on the same channel and I can use them individually to read and write data separately.

You can replicate it using the `marble` chaincode, installing it with different names on the same peer.

In one of them (A) I implemented invokeChaincode(B), to read data stored by B in this way:

```
func (chaincode *SimpleChaincode) queryMarblesFromAnotherChaincode(stub shim.ChaincodeStubInterface, args []string) peer.Response {

    queryMarble := "queryMarble"

    if len(args) != 3 {
        return shim.Error("Incorrect number of arguments. Expecting 3")
    }

    chaincodeName := args[0]
    chaincodeArgs := toChaincodeArgs(queryMarble, args[1])
    chaincodeChannel := args[2]

    response := stub.InvokeChaincode(chaincodeName, chaincodeArgs, chaincodeChannel)
    if response.Status != shim.OK {
        return shim.Error(fmt.Sprintf("Failed to query chaincode: %s", response.Payload))
    }
    return shim.Success(response.Payload)
}
```

Running that method using `peer chaincode invoke ..` , 
I receive `status: 200`, but Payload is empty.

Could you advise on what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `shim.success(response.Payload)` is empty its most likely that chaincode B is returning an empty payload. To be sure try logging what `response.Payload` here in chaincode A before returning.

In addition, add some logging to chaincode B so you can see exactly what chaincode B is supposedly returning to chaincode A.

Comment: It looks I was calling the wrong function `queryMarble` instead of `queryMarbles`, and func Invoke returned `nil` by default.
Fixed now, thanks for the tip!